# How to build a module separately in multimodular maven project?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, multi-module, revision

Following [maven-ci-friendly](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) article in official Maven documentation, this multimodule project ([minimal example](https://github.com/diziaq/sample-maven-modular-revision)) was created.

There are three modules and a root project (inception):

```
/inception
  /modules
    /base     (common parent of 'core' and 'facade')
    /core     (child of 'base')
    /facade   (child of 'base' having 'core' as a dependency)
```

Executing `mvn package` from `inception` works as expected - all 3 `*.jar` artifacts are being created in the corresponding `target` forlders.

I would like to have an option of **building `facade` module separately**.
Unfortunately, `mvn package` from `modules/facade` fails to collect dependencies and fails with error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sample-facade:
        Could not resolve dependencies for project sample.group:sample-facade:jar:0.0.1:
        Failed to collect dependencies at sample.group:sample-core:jar:0.0.1: 
        Failed to read artifact descriptor for sample.group:sample-core:jar:0.0.1:
        Could not transfer artifact sample.group:sample-base:pom:${revision}
```

The surface problem is that `${revision}` is not being resolved into `0.0.1`.

---

Could you help me workaround this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module)

Comment: @Zinc Thank you for the reference. But that does not approach to the problem, which comes from the unresolved `revision` property.

Comment: May be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086512/maven-issue-to-build-one-module-using-revision-property) is your problem. Which version of maven are you using ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven issue to build one module using revision property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086512/maven-issue-to-build-one-module-using-revision-property)

Comment: @Zinc It's maven 3.6.1+ as described in the minimal example README https://github.com/diziaq/sample-maven-modular-revision

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 yes

Comment: Very important read the documentation of ci friendlly until the end and add the flatten-maven-plugin which is not part of your pom .... Furthermore your example lacks on parent cause you have one level of directory without a pom file https://github.com/diziaq/sample-maven-modular-revision/tree/main/modules ... which means all the submodules should be moved one level up within directory hierarchy...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks a lot. Yes, `flatten-maven-plugin` is the key. But the directory hierarchy does not affect the problem -- the project can be built with the given structure. The only prerequisite is installing `core` and `base` into local maven repo before calling `package` on `facade`.

Comment: If you need to `install` then your build is broken... the directory structure is one of the issues. It would make your handling easier ...Why does have `facade` `base` as parent? and not the one level higher? And configure everything in the root https://github.com/diziaq/sample-maven-modular-revision/blob/main/pom.xml ? You seemed to misunderstand a multi module build....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `flatten-maven-plugin` solves the problem.
Thanks to @khmarbaise, who adviced in the comments reading [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) to the end.

Adding the plugin to `/modules/base/pom.xml` solved the problem with building a submodule separately:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
      <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>flatten</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>flatten</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>flatten.clean</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Before starting a phase on `facade` module, it is required to have `base` and `core` in the local repository, so maven could find the artifacts. Hence, here is the sequence of actions in root:

- `mvn install -pl modules/base,modules/core` (or just `mvn install`)
- `mvn package -pl modules/facade`

Comment: I recommend the docs because I have written them... ;-)